# PowerShell command lets for TFS2013

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am using TFS 2013. I have installed Power tools 2013 update 2 on my local machine.
I have tried to use this `Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'microsoft.teamfoundation.powershell.` on both the 32 and the 64 bit version of power shell and  I get the following error.

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'microsoft.teamfoundation.powershell' is not installed on this machine.
```

I have tried to look and read through a few forums but in vain.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall Power tools 2013 and re install to get the options that explained PowerTools cmdlets can be installed only if I installed Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu.
Before that I had tried Repair multiple times but had not helped.